# What is the meaning of *table[17]?

Tags: c++

What is *table[17] in the given code? Does it just make 17 copies of the structure?

```
struct node
{
  string key;
  string no;
  node *next;
}*table[17];
```

Comment: `*new`? No way it's C++

Comment: Just a pointer replace it with any name doesnt matter

Comment: 1) consider reading a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It creates an array containing 17 pointers to `node` (`node*`). 2) Does this code even compile? `new` is a keyword in C++ language.

Comment: It matters a great deal. Shows the difference between nonsense cooked up on the spot, and genuine code one is asking about. Read about how one should create a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the meaning of *table[17]?

It is a declarator. It declares a variable of type `*node[17]` with name `table`. That is an array of 17 pointers to `node`.

> Does it just make 17 copies of the structure?

No. No `node` objects will be made.

Answer (score 2):

> What is *table[17]?

The meaning of this line of code `...}*table[17];` is, you have defined a `struct node` and declared an array of type `node pointer` and size of that pointer array is to store 17 node element/object pointers. So in ***table*** array you can store the ***address*** of 17 node elements.

For example:-

```
    struct node a, b, c, d ....,p;         
    table[0] = &a;//storing the address of a;
    table[1] = &b;//storing the address of b;
    table[2] = &c;//storing the address of c;
    .
    .
    .
    table[16] = &p;//storing the address of p;
```

or dynamically:-

```
      for( int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
          table[0] =  new node();// in C (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

> Does it just make 17 copies of the structure?

No it is just an array of 17 pointers. You have to assign the address of element of type ***node*** in each location. Hence you have to create each node element like I did above. Hope this will help you.